# SQL - Extend outcome of INSERT query with additional query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I have a simple `INSERT` query based on a CTE:

```
WITH my_values ( ...)
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT * FROM my_values WHERE ...
RETURNING *;
```

I would like to extend the output with another query. Something like this:

```
WITH my_values ( ...)
SELECT * FROM (
    INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT * FROM my_values WHERE ...
    RETURNING *
) AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT ...;
```

Is this possible in Postgres? I am trying several queries, but keep getting syntax errors.

**update**

Even the following query is not working. I get syntax error at/near 'INTO':

```
WITH my_values ( ...)
SELECT * FROM (
    INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT * FROM my_values WHERE ...
    RETURNING *
) AS t1;
```

I'll try to have the `INSERT` into a CTE as well, but I would like to know what is wrong with above query.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  I would usually express the `insert` as a CTE rather than a subquery.  With your particular syntax, you need a table alias after the subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OK, good to know! I'll keep figuring out the syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I provide an alias after the subquery, PSQL keeps complaining of syntax error near 'INTO'. I'll update my question to include this alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to use CTEs.  Try this:

```
WITH my_values ( ...),
     i as (
      INSERT INTO my_table
          SELECT * FROM my_values WHERE ...
          RETURNING *
    )
SELECT *
FROM i;
```

Comment: This works indeed with CTE! I always thought that a non-recursive CTE could be seen as `a convenience syntax`, but apparently you can express more with it. Good to know, thank you.

Comment: @JadeDezo . . . And I, in turn, had not realized that Postgres's support of `insert`/`update`/`delete` in CTEs doesn't extend to subqueries.  I simply had never tried them in subqueries.